QGIS 3.28 suddenly pixelated interface
I've just come back from a one week holiday and discovered that the interface of QGIS 3.28, which I've been using for more than one year so far on a daily base, is now strangely pixelated and low in resolution both of the icons and the maps canvas. This only affects QGIS and apparently no other program.
I tried in the last two hours everything I could imagine to solve: restart, change in compatibility settings for high DPI, change icons size, change UI theme, upgrade grafics driver, check for any system upgrades that could have happend while I was away. I also uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS. Nothing worked.
Has someone experienced something similar? Any clue?
I am working on a Full HD display with detail of windows '95 -.-'
here some screenshots:


Already checked:
QGIS 3.22.1 changelog: physical DPI
https://danantonielli.com/app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix-2019/
QGIS is slow and vectors have low resolution

A reinstall doesn't change the QGIS app data folder in your user folder.  If you have a lot of customizations or plugins you could make note of them, and then rename the QGIS app data folder (e.g. add old to the folder name) and start to see if that changes things.  If it doesn't help you can delete the new replacement app data folder and rename the old one back to its original.  There are also registry edits in the QGIS folder that could be made but that's only for those who have worked with the Registry.
